# Outsourcing a Subtask to 2nd CPU and getting results when available

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing, subprocess

I would like to achieve the following. Obviously, i already researched a lot but I wasn't really able to get my head around it  fully. Hence, I would appreciate any help:

Let's say I am in a `while True do stuff` loop, in which I execute a bunch of tasks all over. The exit point of the loop is not important for my problem. Now I have one task within that loop that is a bit more time consuming and hence delays everything. However I **do not** need the result of that task necessarily to further execute my while loop. I would like to take that specific sub task and push it to a 2nd CPU. In the main loop (on CPU 1) I would ask for the result of this subtask from CPU 2. If it is not there yet I continue without it and if it is there I grab it, use it and would push again a new subtask to CPU 2. The creation of the result of this subtask should however be performed on CPU 2.

```
while True:
    do stuff
    check for results on CPU 2
    if results there take them and push new subtask to CPU 2
    if results not there simply continue with other stuff
```

I read about multiprocessing, but I have the feeling that they are using always the same (data heavy) tasks and push them onto multiple CPUs. I also do that for e.g. Reinforcement Learning stuff. But I haven't seen this outsourcing of a subtasks and occasionally asking for the result.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of doing what you want using a multiprocessing pool to which you can submit long-running tasks to execute in another CPU while the main process continues execution.  I have also added code which shows how you could gracefully terminate if and when a condition arises that causes you to break out of your forever loop. Please read the comments carefully:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
import time

def long_running_task(some_argument):
    ... # process
    time.sleep(1) # simulate a long running task
    result = 'some result'
    print(result)
    return result

def process_loop():
    # We create a pool whose size is the number of CPU
    # cores we have less 1 for the main process to use.
    # If you want to only use one additional CPU, then specify Pool(1):
    pool = Pool(cpu_count() - 1)
    # Hold multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult instances:
    unfinished_tasks = set()

    # Assume some condition exists that causes us to break out of our loop.
    # For this demo, we will just loop 4 times:
    for _ in range(4):
        ... #do stuff
        time.sleep(.5) # simulate short-running task
        # If we need to perform a long running task:
        unfinished_tasks.add(pool.apply_async(long_running_task, args=('some argument',)))

        # This will hold newly completed tasks:
        completed_tasks = set()
        # This wil hold newly started tasks:
        new_tasks = set()
        # Test if any submitted tasks have completed
        for task in unfinished_tasks:
            if task.ready(): # Task has completed
                # get return value from task:
                return_value = task.get()
                # Show completed:
                completed_tasks.add(task)
                # Use result to create another task.
                new_tasks.add(pool.apply_async(long_running_task, args=(return_value,)))
        # Compute new unfinished_tasks:
        unfinished_tasks = (unfinished_tasks | new_tasks) - completed_tasks

    # Wait for unfnished tasks to complete:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_loop()
```

A second way, which you may find simpler, is to use a *callback* function that gets called whenever a previously submitted task completes.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
import time

def long_running_task(some_argument):
    ... # process
    time.sleep(1) # simulate a long running task
    return 'some result'

def process_loop():
    stop_flag = False

    # Gets invoked on when a submitted task completes:
    def my_callback(return_value):
        print(return_value)
        if not stop_flag:
            # Submit new task using return value from current completed task.
            pool.apply_async(long_running_task, args=(return_value,), callback=my_callback)

    # We create a pool whose size is the number of CPU
    # cores we have less 1 for the main process to use.
    # If you want to only use one additional CPU, then specify Pool(1):
    pool = Pool(cpu_count() - 1)
    
    # Instead of a loop "forever", we have some condition that causes
    # us to break out of the loop. For this demo we just loop 4 times:
    for _ in range(4):
        ... #do stuff
        time.sleep(.5) # simulate a short-running task
        # If we need to perform a long running task:
        pool.apply_async(long_running_task, args=('some argument',), callback=my_callback)
    # Prevent new tasks being submitted by our callback:
    stop_flag = True
    # Wait for outstanding tasks to complete:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_loop()
```

Comment: Thank you, those are very clear and helpful code examples that fully answer my query! Will play around with them asap